# Print a comma except on the last line in Awk

Tags: shell, awk, separator

I have the following script

```
awk '{printf "%s", $1"-"$2", "}' $a >> positions;
```

where `$a` stores the name of the file. I am actually writing multiple column values into one row. However, I would like to print a comma only if I am not on the last line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it by finding the number of lines before running the script, e.g. with coreutils and bash:

```
awk -v nlines=$(wc -l < $a) '{printf "%s", $1"-"$2} NR != nlines { printf ", " }' $a >>positions
```

If your file only has 2 columns, the following coreutils alternative also works. Example data:

```
paste <(seq 5) <(seq 5 -1 1) | tee testfile
```

Output:

```
1   5
2   4
3   3
4   2
5   1
```

Now replacing tabs with newlines, `paste` easily assembles the date into the desired format:

```
 <testfile tr '\t' '\n' | paste -sd-,
```

Output:

```
1-5,2-4,3-3,4-2,5-1
```

Comment: FYI, this usage of `tr` and `paste` should work in any POSIX environment, it's not restricted to GNU coreutils.

Answer (score 25):

Single pass approach:

```
cat "$a" | # look, I can use this in a pipeline! 
  awk 'NR > 1 { printf(", ") } { printf("%s-%s", $1, $2) }'
```

Note that I've also simplified the string formatting.

Comment: Hey look, you could also use `awk < "$a" 'Nr ...'` and it would work in one process (no cats)!

Comment: @KrzysztofJabłoński I realize that a fanatical hatred for use of `cat` is de rigueur here, but your alternative misses the point entirely. Other answers were dependent on a multi-pass approach that disallowed usage in a pipeline, which I showed here to be possible.

Comment: I agree, that the intended point was to show the usage in pipeline. Apparently I disagree on usage of `cat` for that purpose. Too often I see that humble command harnessed to starting a pipeline. To illustrate the idea, I'd prefer showing something like `dataGeneratorCmd | dataFilterCmd | awk '...' | terminalConsumerCmd`. But that's a matter of taste and preference. Anyway, don't feel offended. This is still a fairly comprehensive answer. +1

Comment: @KrzysztofJabłoński I'm not offended. But I am rather tired of the way that far too many people feel the need to comment about use of `cat`, even when there is a good reason for it that has been explicitly stated.

Comment: I think this is a better answer then the one accepted.

Answer (score 15):

Enjoy this one:

```bash
awk '{printf t $1"-"$2} {t=", "}' $a >> positions
```

Yeh, looks a bit tricky at first sight. So I'll explain, first of all let's change `printf` onto `print` for clarity:

```bash
awk '{print t $1"-"$2} {t=", "}' file
```

and have a look what it does, for example, for file with this simple content:

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
```

so it will produce the following:

```
 1-A
 , 2-B
 , 3-C
 , 4-D
```

The trick is the preceding `t` variable which is empty at the beginning. The variable will be set `{t=...}` only on the next step of processing after it was shown `{print t ...}`. So if we (`awk`) continue iterating we will got the desired sequence.

Comment: Your answer appeared in the low quality review queue. Please edit your answer to include a description of how this works.

Comment: This solution IMHO is better than accepted answer because the number of lines sometimes impossible or difficult to calculate before awk. For example in case I want wak to exit if empty line encountered

Comment: This is nice, but if you print the lines based on a condition to skip some header lines, it won't work since after skipping the first one, `t` gots assigned. It works then by using the same condition for the `{t=", "}` but it seems a bit dirty for me. Ex: `$1 ~ /^[0-9]*$/ {print t $1} $1 ~ /^[0-9]*$/ {t = ", "}` isn't there any cleaner solution?

Comment: @r1verside use a separate call to `grep` or `awk` to filter out the lines you don't want, then pipe that result to @rook's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You might think that awk's ORS and OFS would be a reasonable way to handle this:

```
$ awk '{print $1,$2}' OFS="-" ORS=", " input.txt
```

But this results in a final ORS because the input contains a newline on the last line. The newline is a record separator, so from awk's perspective there is an empty last record in the input. You can work around this with  a bit of hackery, but the resultant complexity eliminates the elegance of the one-liner.

So here's my take on this. Since you say you're "writing multiple column values", it's possible that mucking with ORS and OFS would cause problems. So we can achieve the desired output entirely with formatting.

```
$ cat input.txt
3 2
5 4
1 8
$ awk '{printf "%s%d-%d",t,$1,$2; t=", "} END{print ""}' input.txt
3-2, 5-4, 1-8
```

This is similar to Michael's and rook's single-pass approaches, but it uses a single `printf` and correctly uses the format string for formatting.

This will likely perform negligibly better than Michael's solution because an assignment should take less CPU than a test, and noticeably better than any of the multi-pass solutions because the file only needs to be read once.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way, without resorting to coreutils:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { c++; next } { ORS = (FNR==c ? "\n" : ", "); print $1, $2 }' OFS="-" file file
```

Comment: Why is this better than Thor's? When would you have `awk` but not `wc`?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber: A broken installation is the short answer. Regardless, it is much more awkish to simply write some code that emulates `wc -l < file` on the first pass then manipulate `ORS` as required on the second pass. Easy. Also, your answer is incomplete. You'll need yet another print statement in the `END` block to correct for a missing newline character at EOF. That's three print statements most of which don't do anything, really. On big files, your approach will be slow. Sarathi's answer will also be slow for very large files, because each line is added to memory and that's not ideal.

Comment: Also, Thor has used two print statements when only one is really necessary. He's added a quick fix, when what was required was a re-write. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{a[NR]=$1"-"$2;next}END{for(i=1;i<NR;i++){print a[i]", " }}' $a > positions
```